# knowing which regions are being pressed on a image, for all screen sizes of android devices

Tags: android, image

What I need is to be able to know which regions on a image is being pressed, I have a piece of image taken from google earth, and there are some buildings that are relevant, the way that i am using right now is to place images with low alpha so they are transparent and placing them on top of the buildings, and implementing onTouchListener on them, but the problem with this is that only works on certain android devices, for example on an Samsung galaxy 4 they are on wrong places.

I need to be able to detect this buildings that are being pressed regardless of the screen resolution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the touch events on the image to detect where the press happens:

```
this.view.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event)
    {           
        final int x = (int) event.getRawX();
        final int y = (int) event.getRawY();
    }
}
```

You will need to scale the X and Y coordinates by the size of the view to get the position touched within the original image.